# Can $\ a^k+b^k+c^k\ $ be prime for $\ k\in\{0,\ldots, m\}$ arbitary large?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\ a,b,c\ $ be integers with $\ 0<a<b<c\ $ and let $\ m\ $ be the smallest non-negative integer such that $$a^m+b^m+c^m$$ is composite.

Define $$f(a,b,c)=m-1$$ Hence $\ f(a,b,c)\ $ is the largest non-negative integer $\ m\ $ such that $$a^k+b^k+c^k$$ is prime for $\ k=0,\cdots ,m\ $. Since for $\ k=0\ $, we get always $\ 3\ $ which is a prime, $\ f(a,b,c)\ $ is always non-negative.

> Has $f(a,b,c)$ a maximum ?

I have found $$f(2, 186, 803)=8$$ with brute force, that means that $\ 2^k+186^k+803^k\ $ is prime for $\ k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\ $ which is unbeaten , if $\ c\le 1000\ $ holds.

Comment: The hypotehsis that prime-number question always receive a downvote is still alive !

Comment: I have a gut feeling that a maximum should exist. Otherwise, there is a triple $(a,b,c)$ such that for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $a^k+b^k+c^k$ produces prime numbers! That is we have a machine which outputs only prime numbers. I maybe very wrong, but that seems too good to be true to me. However, it might be possible that $\sup_{(a,b,c)}f(a,b,c)=\infty$.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay This is not what I mean. I mean whether we can find a triple $\ (a,b,c)\ $ for every given $\ m\ $

Comment: I am confused, if $m$ is given then $f(a,b,c)$ is given, then the question *Has $f(a,b,c)$ a maximum?* does not make sense to me. Are you trying to ask whether there is a triple $(a,b,c)$ such that, for a given $m$, $a^{k}+b^k+c^k$ is prime for all integers $k$ such that $0\le k\le m-1$?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay The question basically is : If we give $m$, is there a triple $(a,b,c)$ with $f(a,b,c)\ge m$ ?

Comment: I think that is what I tried to address in the last line of my first comment. Your question basically amounts to finding whether $\sup_{a,b,c}f(a,b,c)=\infty$. Am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104559/discussion-between-peter-and-samrat-mukhopadhyay).

Comment: The triple $$(212, 1260, 1695)$$ gives $\ m=9\ $

Comment: The triple $$(2622, 2768, 2801)$$ gives $\ m=10\ $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104576/discussion-between-peter-and-samrat-mukhopadhyay).

Comment: Is it clear that the corresponding "two-variate" function (defined for $a^k+b^k$) is bounded?

Comment: @W-t-P $(a+b)$ divides $a^3+b^3$ so it's bounded at $m=2$.